# I need to convert this Json Facebook Pages to array for select

Tags: javascript, json

i need to change this code json to a select list because i try to work of fan page of facebook, but i dont kwno how construct a list with parse json and for o foreach and i want to know if you can help me

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "access_token": "EASDASDASD",
      "category": "Producto/servicio",
      "category_list": [
        {
          "id": "2201231",
          "name": "Producto/servicio"
        },
        {
          "id": "50133821238",
          "name": "salsas"
        },
        {
          "id": "178669642112378193",
          "name": "Salsa"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Salsa Verde",
      "id": "283585512310",
      "tasks": [
        "ANALYZE",
        "ADVERTISE",
        "MODERATE",
        "CREATE_CONTENT",
        "MANAGE"
      ]
    },
    {
      "access_token": "KLAKSDKASDLASD",
      "category": "Escuela",
      "category_list": [
        {
          "id": "551123691940",
          "name": "Escuela"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Escuela de Altura",
      "id": "458438357842766",
      "tasks": [
        "ANALYZE",
        "ADVERTISE",
        "MODERATE",
        "CREATE_CONTENT",
        "MANAGE"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "WAsdaWq",
      "after": "ND4MzQWeqweQyNzY2"
    }
  }
}
```

to same like this, i need to print all pages with a list.

```
<ul class="list-group" id="data1">
<li class="list-group-item">name</li>
<li class="list-group-item">category</li>
<li class="list-group-item">aceess_token</li>
<li class="list-group-item">category_list: id</li>
<li class="list-group-item">category_list: name</li>
</ul>
<br><hr>
<ul class="list-group" id="data2">
<li class="list-group-item">name</li>
<li class="list-group-item">category</li>
<li class="list-group-item">aceess_token</li>
<li class="list-group-item">category_list: id</li>
<li class="list-group-item">category_list: name</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-group" id="data3">
<li class="list-group-item">name</li>
<li class="list-group-item">category</li>
<li class="list-group-item">aceess_token</li>
<li class="list-group-item">category_list: id</li>
<li class="list-group-item">category_list: name</li>
</ul>
```

can you help me?
i need to construct the list with the info

Comment: What is the relation between the posted JSON data and the HTML markup below? What is your question?

Comment: i need to create a  html list with the json

Comment: sorry if i don't explain me

Comment: Well you don't have any specific problem, you just want us to give you the code. This is why it's hard to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var j = {
  "data": [
    {
      "access_token": "EASDASDASD",
      "category": "Producto/servicio",
      "category_list": [
        {
          "id": "2201231",
          "name": "Producto/servicio"
        },
        {
          "id": "50133821238",
          "name": "salsas"
        },
        {
          "id": "178669642112378193",
          "name": "Salsa"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Salsa Verde",
      "id": "283585512310",
      "tasks": [
        "ANALYZE",
        "ADVERTISE",
        "MODERATE",
        "CREATE_CONTENT",
        "MANAGE"
      ]
    },
    {
      "access_token": "KLAKSDKASDLASD",
      "category": "Escuela",
      "category_list": [
        {
          "id": "551123691940",
          "name": "Escuela"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Escuela de Altura",
      "id": "458438357842766",
      "tasks": [
        "ANALYZE",
        "ADVERTISE",
        "MODERATE",
        "CREATE_CONTENT",
        "MANAGE"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "WAsdaWq",
      "after": "ND4MzQWeqweQyNzY2"
    }
  }
};

var markup = '';

for (var x = 0; x < j.data.length; x++) {
  markup += '<ul class="list-group" id="data' + (x + 1) + '">';
  markup += '<li class="list-group-item">' +  j.data[x].name + '</li>';
  markup += '<li class="list-group-item">' +  j.data[x].category + '</li>';
  markup += '<li class="list-group-item">' +  j.data[x].access_token + '</li>';
  markup += '<li class="list-group-item">' +  j.data[x].category_list[0].id + '</li>';
  markup += '<li class="list-group-item">' +  j.data[x].category_list[0].name + '</li>';
  markup += '</ul>';
}

document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = markup;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```